# Flow not detecting if-block handling potentially undefined (maybe) value. Why?

Tags: javascript, redux, flowtype

I am seeing a behavior in Flow that I don't understand. The function that I'm trying to type is a redux reducer. The problem that I'm seeing seems to stem from the fact that the `action` object provided to the reducer has a payload that is marked with the "maybe" operator: `?`. That type looks like this essentially:

```
type Action = {
  type: 'foo',
  payload?: { ... }
}
```

In the reducer I tried to provide an if-gate to handle the case when `payload` is not defined. In theory, it seems this should work. The simplest case works (see [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKpIC4oDkAZggQDSZRgCGIANnNQCYD8+GWWJc+xplAX3QCA3OnQ5oAIWoAnZGkqTeAIznlKNeo1btKWNbNXqKWIaPEBjOADsAzsCiyITAK6WI8lAAoH1YBDsAgqoAmRQ1JbAAJa2+PCIAD5QMrIAlMgAfIpYdgDu0cCWABZQ3pExtgB0khkcnJbUdtB8cAR6nJzRRGUAhBWxNlVaDMx1+p1OEMCusjZQfgFik1BCK84zcxFRg8O0o0xV3Mucaw1NLYbtOZPdfQPVIzrjK1gbs-OLECedZ53vWweQyezCqhh+qwmTAgRGorjowFwEze0w+C2A-m+gmEQA)):

```
type Foo = {
  type: 'foo',
  payload?: {
    foo: 'foo'
  }
};

type Bar = {
  type: 'bar',
  payload?: {
    bar: 'bar',
  }
};

const reducer = (state: {} = {}, action: Foo | Bar) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'foo': {
      if (!action.payload) {
        return state;
      }
      return action.payload.foo;
    }
    case 'bar': {
      if (!action.payload) {
        return state;
      }
      return action.payload.bar;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

However, in my actual reducer, which is a bit more involved, I'm unable to do away with the errors. My reducer looks something like this:

```
const camelize = (x) => x;
const getSearchTypeFromPath = (x) => x;

type A = {
  type: '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE',
  payload?: {
    pathname: string,
    query: {},
  }
}

type B = {
  type: 'action.foo',
  payload?: {
    mode: string,
    params: {}
  }
}

const byMode = (
  state: {} = {},
  action: A | B,
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE': {
      if (!action.payload) {
        return state;
      }

      const modeKey: string = camelize(getSearchTypeFromPath(action.payload.pathname));
      return {
        ...state,
        [modeKey]: action.payload.query,
      };
    }
    case 'action.foo': {
      if (!action.payload) {
        return state;
      }

      const modeKey: string = camelize(action.payload.mode);
      return {
        ...state,
        [modeKey]: action.payload.params,
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This code, unlike the simplified case above, produces some flow errors: see [here](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBMCGBbApgGwJYC9kwLwwAoAPASjwD4YiBuAKFElgHNkoBlZeAJ2AAsAVAJ4AHZADEuIRAAV4UXnkKkKVOrSgicAQUUBvWjBgbRALhgByAAKXJAVyjIuAegAyAeQDCW-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):

```
33:         [modeKey]: action.payload.query,
                                      ^ Cannot get `action.payload.query` because property `query` is missing in undefined [1].
References:
6:   payload?: {               ^ [1]
44:         [modeKey]: action.payload.params,
                                      ^ Cannot get `action.payload.params` because property `params` is missing in undefined [1].
References:
14:   payload?: {                ^ [1]
```

In terms of the logic gate handling the possibly undefined `payload` they are I think the same. So why the error? It's also interesting that there is no error for the first properties that are referenced in each case block: i.e. `pathname` and `mode`. Finally, one other thing I noticed is that if I remove the helper functions, which in my example here have just been turned into dummy functions, then I don't get the errors. See [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKVSQFxQOQAF8AnAewFdgIiB6AGQHkBhGAFQEl6A5AfUYAkYnAOIBRXABo0UMAEMQAGxIyAJgH4cqdOlnAAFgDsZAWwg4AzsCIBLfQHNJWqAEcyVEBoC+DqB5S+UmNAAQgjIUoE4uDIAxsBWJPoAdABmJCQSUrIKSmoaUuhGJMqmUBbWdt7aMkTGZp5Svv7RCRZQAEYgALJF0IgAFFIWMpSeoUheUjFxCThwAD5QQZIAlAgAfGHoZgDuVsDRulB9U-FJgauaWtEyZtAExOSUNAzM7Fy8AsJieY7oVslHACEJwSiSyihUF3yvyIEGAZCI+lKwGGEAA3ND0L5flBMVBmvpWoVigBpCDuZHlWyhEFJcE5MHDAzGdF42HwxGbHFQRK8oaUSq-ADaxIgZJAAF0cLTGdkVIkXG5BViMY5sVcbncZal0j9fv8gTL6ZCuTj2QikfzWTj1Y48QSiT1xeZLDZqYgjXIIcpEqLVTC4RbTb9eYkrcqtCKneSpVBPXKfbIakYzBHbT5ocVkjIyPJgFg2YHOVb-Y00UA).

Is there anyone out there that can explain what's going on here. I can't make sense of it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the call to `camelize`.

Flow resets all type refinements after a function call where that function call could potentially mutate a value. In your example, `action` is a parameter, so it's plausible that something like this happens:

```
function camelize(x) {
   someAction.payload = undefined;
}

// Now your code crashes
byMode({}, someAction);
```

Generally the solution is to extract out the thing being tested into a `const`:

```
const payload = action.payload;
if (payload === undefined) return;
// OK to use 'payload' after function calls now
```

See also https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations or e.g. https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5393

Answer (score 0):

```
type A = {
type: '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE',
payload: {
  pathname: string,
  query: {},
 }
}

type B = {
type: 'action.foo',
payload: {
  mode: string,
  params: {}
 }
}
```

Don't know the purpose of **?** but by removing this will remove your errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not a solution. The ? operator indicates that the 'payload' is sometimes not present. These types approximate a general type that comes from the flow typed library for flux-standard-actions.

Comment: see [here](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/flux-standard-action_v1.x.x/flow_v0.38.x-/flux-standard-action_v1.x.x.js) for the flux-standard-action type that I'm approximating in the example above:

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to get this to work is to add some ternary checks for each of the references to those properties even after the logic gate like this:

```
const camelize = (x) => x;
const getSearchTypeFromPath = (x) => x;

type A = {
  type: '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE',
  payload?: {
    pathname: string,
    query: {},
  }
}

type B = {
  type: 'action.foo',
  payload?: {
    mode: string,
    params: {}
  }
}

const byMode = (
  state: {} = {},
  action: A | B,
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE': {
      if (!action.payload) {
        throw new Error('Ooops');
      }

      const modeKey: string = camelize(getSearchTypeFromPath(action.payload ? action.payload.pathname : ''));
      return {
        ...state,
        [modeKey]: action.payload ? action.payload.query: {},
      };
    }
    case 'action.foo': {
      if (!action.payload) {
        return state;
      }

      const modeKey: string = camelize(action.payload.mode || '');
      return {
        ...state,
        [modeKey]: action.payload ? action.payload.params : {},
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

See [here](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBMCGBbApgGwJYC9kwLwwAoAPASjwD4YiBuAKFElgHNkoBlZeAJ2AAsAVAJ4AHZADEuIRAAV4UXnkKkKVOrSgicAQUUBvWjBgbRALhgByAAKXJAVyjIuAegAyAeQDCW-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-9nduMkXu+X0r6uMcg7GfgVKcGxqbZpngWxUCgExw0jaNdXeetzmoIA) for example.

I don't understand why this works even though the code in question wouldn't be reached if `action.payload` is undefined. The code required to please flow in this case seems less than ideal as it requires checks that don't seem necessary.